# Get "ul class" value and "li class" value from HTML page with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I want to extract data from a web site using VBA.
I have managed to extract some part of the output, but is not a complete one.

Could anyone give me a hint about my code?

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="lc">
  <div class="mbox0px">
    <ul class="menu country-list">
      <li class="head">Countries</li>
      <li id="lmenu_17">
        <a href="/soccer/england/" onclick="return cjs.dic.get('Helper_Menu').lmenu(17,req_url,1);">England</a>
        <ul class="submenu hidden" data-ajax="true">
          <li class="" data-mt="1_17_nwPDBpVc">
            <a href="/soccer/england/premier-league/">Premier League</a>
          </li>
          <li class="" data-mt="1_198_2DSCa5fE">
            <a href="/soccer/england/championship/">Championship</a>
          </li>
          <li class="" data-mt="1_198_rJSMG3H0">
            <a href="/soccer/england/league-one/">League One</a>
        </li>
```

The results should be in each consecutive cell like below:

```
England
Premier League
Championship
League One
```

My VBA code is below:

```
Sub Get_Link_Name()

Dim URL As String
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim NewCollection As Object: Set dictObj = New Collection
Dim tRowID As String

URL = "http://www.flashscore.ro/"

With ie
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = .document
End With


With HTMLdoc

    Set tblSet = .getElementById("lc")
    Set mTbl = tblSet.getElementsByTagName("ul")(4)
    Set tRows = mTbl.getElementsByTagName("li")

    With NewCollection

        i = 2
        For Each trow In tRows

                tRowText = trow.innerText
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = tRowText
                i = i + 1
                'MsgBox tRowText

        Next trow
    End With
End With

Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want the actual results for England.

The URL are set up with a base string (path) of `https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/` followed by country e.g. `"anglia"`, for England, then the league/championship name.

So you can navigate to each required results table with:

1. https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/premier-league/
2. https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/championship/
3. https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/league-one/
4. https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/league-two/

An example of looping to write one of those tables out to the sheet is using the premier-league table which is obtained simply with `"https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/`"

You may need to tweak this for each link but it shows you how to grab a table, how to loop the rows and columns of a table, how to add "'" before the score to stop it being treated either as a date or as a mathematical evaluation etc.

---

**Website sample:**

[image: Sample]

---

**Code output in sheet (sample):**

[image: Sample 2]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, sResponse As String, hTable As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do: DoEvents: On Error Resume Next: Set hTable = .document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0): On Error GoTo 0: Loop While hTable Is Nothing

        Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tCurr As Object, r As Long, c As Long
        r = 1
        With ActiveSheet
            For Each tRow In hTable.Rows
                For Each tCell In tRow.Cells
                    c = c + 1
                    Select Case c
                    Case 5
                        .Cells(r, c) = "'" & tCell.innerText
                    Case Else
                        .Cells(r, c) = tCell.innerText
                    End Select
                Next tCell
                c = 0: r = r + 1
            Next tRow
        End With
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```